# Why does memoir class encode the contents of .idx file and how can it still be used to produce a properly sorted Russian index?

Tags: memoir, unicode, makeindex

When using the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491055/201502) I faced the following error message on the 2nd pass (with `pdflatex`):

> Undefined control sequence. \item \T

It originates from the entry in the `.ind` file:

```
\item \T2A\CYRD \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrz , \hyperpage{224}
```

In turn it is generated by the following entry in the `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{\T2A\CYRD \T2A\cyro \T2A\cyrz |hyperpage}{224}
```

If I switch `memoir` to `article` or `book` then the index contains the entries defined in the document verbatim, without them being encoded.

The following MWE can be used to validate:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\rindex}[1]{\expandafter\index\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}}

\begin{document} 
жзи\rindex{жзи}
\clearpage
где\rindex{где}
\clearpage
абв\rindex{абв}
\clearpage
эюя\rindex{эюя}
\clearpage
шщы\rindex{шщы}
\clearpage
клм\rindex{клм}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

It passes the 1st pass, then command `texindy -L russian -C utf8 "document.idx"` generates the `.ind` file, and the 2nd pass fails.

Comment: You may want to consider updating your TeX system. I have a fully updated system with `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3` and get `\indexentry{жзи}{1}` etc. in the `.idx` file. I think I remember that LaTeX 2019-10-01 brought great improvements for Unicode handling in pdfLateX in some areas. Alternatively it might be a good idea to switch to a Unicode engine like XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you. I am on TL 2018 and am staying on it due to hardware and software constraints out of scope of this question.

Comment: I think that for this to work the following package has to be used: `\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer right after posting the question, as it often happens.

For that to work the following package has to be included:

```
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
```

and the

```
\usepackage{makeindex}
```

has to be removed.